# Change Angular Material input required style

Tags: css, input, angular-material2, required

I am using Angular 4, recently added Material to the project. I added the required attribute to Angular Material input component as below:

```html
<md-form-field >
    <input mdInput placeholder="Obligatoire" [(ngModel)]="value" required>
</md-form-field>
```

When the field is not valid the asterisk, the placeholder and the line have become red but not all instantly.

Is there a way to play with the transition time from blue --> red (valid -->invalid) otherwise made the change from blue to red instantly.

[input required image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWin9.png)

Comment: What do you mean by instant?  The required field will only toggle if you select the input and then navigate away from it.

Comment: The asterisk and the line are becoming red before the placeholder, meaning there is a latency on the placeholder to change his coloration compared to the asterisk and the line. I am trying to make the coloration change for all three instantly when it's required.